# .net core dependency injection with parameters on constructor

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core

In .net core, if I use dependency injection is it true that all the constructor parameters must be provide by DI?

Let's say:

```csharp
public Person CreateClient()
{
    string phone = "12345678";
    return new Person(phoneNumber: phone);        
}

public class Person 
{
    private readonly ISomeService _service;
    private readonly string _phoneNumber;
    public Person (ISomeService service, string phoneNumber)
    {
        _service = service;
        _phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public string PhoneNumber {get { return _phoneNumber; } }
    public string Gender {get { return _service.GetGenderFromDb(); } }
}

public interface ISomeService
{
    String GetGenderFromDb();
}

public class FooService : ISomeService
{
    public String GetGenderFromDb() { return "Male"; }
}
```

Is this possible for DI and value provided by client to stay in same constructor?

Comment: How to register these services in startup ?

Comment: @Ahmar just the normal registration
services.AddTransient<ISomeService, FooService>();

Comment: Ok DI only resolve dependency those register with it. Other parameters not resolved.

Comment: ya, but is there anyway to achieve this? i need both registered dependency and values provided from client as shown in the question.

Comment: create service for `phonenumber` as well and inject it.

Comment: Google or search Stackoverflow for "abstract factory", got to leave for work can't find the reference on the quick

Comment: @Tseng ok thanks, "abstract factory" would best suit this scenario when comparing with "builder" and "factory"? Not very sure how to implement the pattern to solve this problem, should i inject into factory constructor and pass parameters into method inside factory when creating instance?

Comment: You should use builder pattern, when you have a couple of settings which are mostly optional (high number of permutations) and your object is immutable or you return interfaces. For 1 or 2 mandatory parameters, abstract factory is suitable enough. If you inject it in your factory constructor or not depends on the lifetime of your objects. If you need transient life time and multiple calls to the create method should result in different transient instances, you'll need an instance to the container. for scoped or singletons constructor injection works fine with factory pattern

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Anywhere where you are calling "new" to create an object isn't great for doing constructor DI from top to bottom. DI isn't suitable when you want to pass in parameters into constructors.

As others have alluded to, the best way is to create a factory. It might look something like this.

```csharp
public class Person 
{   
    private readonly ISomeService _service;
    private readonly string _phoneNumber;
    public Person (ISomeService service, string phoneNumber)
    {
        _service = service;
        _phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public string PhoneNumber {get { return _phoneNumber; } }
    public string Gender {get { return _service.GetGenderFromDb(); } }
}

public class PersonFactory : IPersonFactory
{
    private readonly ISomeService _someService;

    public PersonFactory(ISomeService someService)
    {
        _someService = someService;
    }

    public GetPerson(string phoneNumber)
    {
        return new Person(_someService, phoneNumber);
    }
}
```

Now when you want to create a person, instead you would inject in an instance of `IPersonFactory`, and call `GetPerson` on it.

Furthermore, you may find that you want your models to be more plain and the factory to do most of the heavy lifting. I see that Gender is coming from the database at the moment, so you may change it to look more like the following :

```csharp
public class Person 
{   
    public Person (string gender, string phoneNumber)
    {
        Gender = gender;
        PhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public string PhoneNumber {get; private set; }
    public string Gender {get; private set;}
}

public class PersonFactory : IPersonFactory
{
    private readonly ISomeService _someService;

    public PersonFactory(ISomeService someService)
    {
        _someService = someService;
    }

    public GetPerson(string phoneNumber)
    {
        var gender = _someService.GetGenderFromDb();
        return new Person(gender, phoneNumber);
    }
}
```

Now your Person class doesn't have any details about where it gets a Gender from, and the factory works out how to create a Person model each time.

Comment: this answer turns out to be same as my implementation after i get the idea from @Tseng suggestions. thanks for posting this answer